# How would I add another extension for deletion when Visual Studio 2008's build->clean / build->rebuild is called?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, configuration

Using VS 2008, C++. I would like to delete all my pch's on a rebuild/build clean. Is there anyway I could add the *.pch files to the list of files to be deleted build->clean or rebuild all? I've looked through Visual Studio options dialog and really can't find anything. Has anyone messed with this in the past?

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I found it. Its in a given project's settings under "Configuration Propertiies"->"General"->"Extensions to Delete on Clean".

No need to upvote me, just thought I'd share.

Comment: +1 so this doesn't show up in the unanswered questions list. ;)